# Given a list create a list of tuples SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

Hello I am new to Sml/nj, and I am trying to modify an input to give it to a function. I'm stuck at modifying the input.

Specifically, I read the input and store it in a list. I want to make a function that given an even length list, it will make a new list, but with 2-element tuples.
For example, if my input is the list `[2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8]` I want to create this list `[(2, 7), (4, 6), (5, 8)]`

I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
fun maketuples [] = []
  | maketuples x::xs = (x, hd xs) @ makektuples (tl xs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple things here:

- If you're pattern matching on a constructor as a function argument, you need to put parentheses around it for it to be parsed the way you'd like, i.e., `x::xs` -> `(x::xs)`
- You have a typo in the second clause (`makektuples`; extra k)
- You're using append (`@`) on a `int * int` and a `(int * int) list`. The domain of this function is in fact, `'a list * 'a list`, i.e., both of its arguments must be lists of the same type.

We could revise this like so:

```ml
fun maketuples [] = []
  | maketuples (x::xs) = [(x, hd xs)] @ maketuples (tl xs)
```

But singleton append isn't really something you should do. Why? It's cleaner to just use cons:

```ml
fun maketuples [] = []
  | maketuples (x::xs) = (x, hd xs) :: maketuples (tl xs)
```

We can clean this up some more by removing the calls to `hd` and `tl` by just destructing further in the function arguments

```ml
fun maketuples [] = []
  | maketuples (x::y::xs) = (x, y) :: maketuples xs
```

and you could perhaps handle an error better (one possibility being with exceptions):

```ml
fun maketuples [] = []
  | maketuples (x::y::xs) = (x, y) :: maketuples xs
  | maketuples _ = raise Fail "Not an even length list"
```